# SQL "Partition" check not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

My below query works fine, it registers new products into different locations based on the latest scan.

My problem is, sometimes i receive products with the same id (that's actually possible). 
In my bellow table there are locations and usually when a produkt reach **location 5** it means it's done and when the a new product gets registered it will always start at **location 1**.
As you can see below i got the product "2222" again and i would like to have my below "FirstScanned" to retrieve **2222', 1, '2017-05-17 15:58** instead of **2222', 1, '2017-03-21 09:50**

```
,min(p.Scanned) over (partition by p.ProductNR) as FirstScanned
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
 (
  ProductNR varchar (14),
  Location int,
  Scanned Datetime
  );
 Insert Into Products(ProductNR, Location, Scanned)
 Values('1111', 1, '2017-03-15 09:30'), 
  ('1111', 2, '2017-03-16 11:35'), 
  ('1111', 3, '2017-03-21 12:37'), 
  ('2222', 1, '2017-03-21 09:50'),
  ('2222', 5, '2017-03-21 12:58');
  ('2222', 1, '2017-05-17 15:58');
```

and the query

```
select p.ProductNR, p.Location, p.Scanned
    ,case
        when p.FirstScanned >= dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) then 'Less than 5 days old'
        when p.FirstScanned <= dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) then 'More than 5 days old'
        else '0'
     end as Age
from
(
    select p.ProductNR
        ,p.Location
        ,p.Scanned
        ,min(p.Scanned) over (partition by p.ProductNR) as FirstScanned
        ,max(p.Scanned) over (partition by p.ProductNR) as LastScanned
    from Products p
) p
where p.LastScanned = p.Scanned
```

Comment: Plus 1 for test data,also add expected result and actual result as well

Comment: Thanks! What I expect is basically if a new produkt registers into my table which already has the same productnr. I'd like my query to only retrieve the new one and not the old one. The old ones are usually defined as closed by location 5 as i explained above and the date is also older

Comment: For 1111 what will be the output? No record selected as there is no record with Location 5?

Comment: 1111 is good since it has not reached Location 5, but product 2222 has been completed on the 2017-03-21 12:58 but it got received again on the 2222', 1, '2017-05-17 15:58. Basically the min(p.scanned) should now point at the 2222', 1, '2017-05-17 15:58 and not at the 2222', 1, '2017-03-21 09:50 if you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH p1 AS (
    SELECT p.ProductNR
        ,p.Location
        ,p.Scanned
    FROM #Products p
    WHERE p.Location <> 5
)  
, p2 AS (
    SELECT p2.ProductNR
        ,p2.Location
        ,p2.Scanned
        ,min(p2.Scanned) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ProductNR) AS FirstScanned
        ,max(p2.Scanned) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ProductNR) AS LastScanned
    FROM p1 p2
)  

SELECT p3.ProductNR
    , p3.Location
    , p3.Scanned
    , CASE 
        WHEN p3.FirstScanned >= dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) THEN 'Less than 5 days old'
        WHEN p3.FirstScanned <= dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) THEN 'More than 5 days old'
        ELSE '0'
     END AS Age
FROM p2 p3
WHERE p3.LastScanned = p3.Scanned
```

Comment: You'll need to filter out the records you don't want to include before you partition. Then do a CTE on a CTE to filter those results.

Comment: I understand your logic, ill give it a try now!